# Use Jinja template for »value«

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Within a playbook one can include Jinja Templated like so:

```
tasks:
  name: 'Foo Bar'
  template:
    src: '~/tmpl/baz.j2'
    dest: '/dev/null'
```

That renders the template and copies it over to the remote host. **But is it possible to use a jinja template to generate a value for a module argument?**

What I would like to do is:

```
tasks:
  name: 'create server'
  a_cloude_server_create:
    …
    user_data: "{{ render(./tmpl/cloud-init.yml.j2) }}"
    …
```

Can that be done?

Comment: I would strongly warn against using '~' in your ansible files. If you want to use environment variables, use them correctly, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/env_lookup.html

Comment: That is just for example … But thanks for that hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use template lookup, as Ansible documentation is bad recently, check local docs for lookup plugin via `ansible-doc -t lookup template`.